# Does Japan and Chinese Buddhism Teach Solipsism or Nihilism?

Tags: nihilism, buddhism, solipsism

Do the modern schools of Buddhism Soto, Rinzai, Jodo-shu, Jodo Shinshu, Nichiren, Shingon in Japan teach Buddhists, Buddhas and Bodhisattvas any varieties of solipsism and any varieties of nihilism?

Do the modern schools of Buddhism Chan, Pure Land in China teach Buddhists, Buddhas and Bodhisattvas any varieties of solipsism and any varieties of nihilism?

Comment: Certainly not nihilism, which is the absence of any belief system.  Buddhism is a belief system.  Not solipsism either, since they are concerned with a cycle of reincarnation that is greater than one person.

Comment: That is: the modern schools of Buddhism Soto, Rinzai, Jodo-shu, Jodo Shinshu, Nichiren, Shingon in Japan do not teach Buddhists, Buddhas and Bodhisattvas to deny that other people have individual minds?  The modern schools of Buddhism Chan, Pure Land in China teach Buddhists, Buddhas and Bodhisattvas to deny that other people have individual minds?

Comment: Not that I've ever heard of.  Indeed "compassion meditation" is a part of some Buddhist schools, where we meditate on connection and compassion with other conscious beings.  There is "anatta" which suggests there is no essential or permanent self, but that's not the same as denying there is any self at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this topic keeps coming up. I think it's because these are used as methods of attack against Buddhist thought.

Buddha taught 'the middle way', between eternalism and nihilism, between an unchanging transcendental soul/identity/essence, and nothing continuing after death - this is typically translated into English as nihilism, though it doesn't conform entirely to the philosophical term. It's from two millennia before, and an entirely different culture so it's no great surprise! The idea Buddhism is nihilist in modern terms of moral nihilism or existential nihilism, are total non-starters. The morality and meaning-cosmology of Buddhist thought are highly developed, although the emphasis on return to your personal situation right now, in priority over any elaborations, can be related to a very specific understanding of nihilism as meaning and purpose never being truly external, absolute, and real outside our own personal experience.

Hindu thought is generally monist, and either non-dualist (advaita) or dualist (dvaita). It's understandable how the monist fusion of transcendental self and 'ultimate reality' can be criticised as a kind of solipsism, and it is a very ancient mode of criticism of Hindu thought. Discussed here: [Different between Buddhism and Solipsism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/different-between-buddhism-and-solipsism/78696#78696)

Buddhist thought deconstructs conventional notions of the self. If there is no unchanging self, how can there be solipsism? Buddhism emphasises sunyata, also called emptiness, dependent origination, and inter-being. This should be understood as an emergent understanding of identity, as conditioned rather than defined by a unique essence, like the bundle-theory of identity developed in Western thought by Hume, and in relation to how identity appears but is not truly personal is best illustrated by the ancient metaphor of [Indra's Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net).

It's worth saying Nchiren Buddhism dismisses previous Buddhist thought, and places Nchiren himself over other authorities, so I wouldn't consider it 'mainstream Buddhism', even though it shares many outward practices and is a widespread school.

The Pureland schools of Jodo Shinshu and Jodo-shu focus on the 'other-power' of Amithaba, instead of self-arising awakening of traditional Zen (Soto & Rinzai). Happy to go into more detail of schools or doctrines if you have further questions.

Relevant discussions:

[How is the concept of "beyond word" viewed in many school of thoughts?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/52713/how-is-the-concept-of-beyond-word-viewed-in-many-school-of-thoughts/52720#52720)

[What are some good resources for learning Indian philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21312/what-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-indian-philosophy/81733#81733)

[Is there anyway to prove things happen/exist if I'm not aware of them?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79815/is-there-anyway-to-prove-things-happen-exist-if-im-not-aware-of-them/79819#79819)

[Why is ontological relativism so hard to digest for many people (philosophers)?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/84431/what-are-the-problems-in-ontological-relativism/84439#84439)

[Does there exist truly objective thoughts?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82262/does-there-exist-truly-objective-thoughts/82289#82289)

Comment: Thanks. All this schools do not forbid Buddhists to believe that other people have separate minds?

Comment: @Jack: Seperate, isolated minds, can only be supported if they have some unchanging essence, something outside of causes and conditions. For Buddhists we are all interconnected, mutually arising, & manifest interbeing. This can be linked to the impossibility of a Private Language in Western thought: conceptual abstract thought, including notions of identity & self (eg, the cogito), require, presuppose, emerge from, collaborative intelligence of language (in Buddhism, alaya vijnana, comparable to noosphere or memesphere)

Comment: ok thanks. When I talk to a Soto or Chan Buddhist, does he believe that I have a mind and a feeling?

Comment: @Jack: I think that's a really weird question. Of course they do. Most Buddhists don't think about the finer points of doctrines, any more than most Christians think about Bishop Berkeley's idea that only the mind of god sustains the reality of things that no one is perceiving. It'd be like asking if Wittgenstein couldn't keep his thoughts to himself. Having said that, you aren't the first person here to ask this. See: 'How do Chinese and Japanese Buddhists perceive people?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/how-do-chinese-and-japanese-buddhists-perceive-people/81465#81465

Comment: I feel like it’s a common misunderstanding especially in English to gloss emptiness as nothingness when it’s more like impermanence/interconnection of things and people which can be conveyed poetically as a “perfect imagelessness” — and more generally the idealism of eg the Lankavatara has to deal with nihilists and materialist doctrines of its era; there is a certain circularity to these transcendental questions that’s interesting to think about. As a middle way between nihilism and materialism, idealism has a very slender path for subtle wisdom to follow — a narrow gate..

Comment: Incidentally there is a Buddhism SE — if OP were to ask his question over there, it would maybe be more likely to get answers from practitioners associated with the schools mentioned

Comment: @JosephWeissman: These comments seem to be unrelated musings, rather than comments on my answer. Unless you are saying I have misrepresented emptiness? I am a Buddhist practicioner, with several of the schools mentioned.

Comment: @CriglCragl thanks for your patience with me! Yes just trying to help clarify some of the confusion here for OP — maybe trying to suggest why this is a common question, but certainly not suggesting this is anything but a great answer and contribution! 

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is an emphatic No.

Nihilism is a western philosophy that developed at roughly the same time as Marxism, though it has earlier roots. It's a position of extreme sceptism. Solipsism is this nihilism viewed from the point of the self.

Buddhism is not a sceptical position. Instead, it points to the impermenance of all things and including the self. This is called *sunyata* which is translated as nothingness. In a sense, no part is ontologically real, only the whole is. So it could equally be translated, with equal justification, as holism which emphasises the interconnection and inter-dependence of all things. However, the traditional term is sunyata.